# What's the best practice for setting up associations with factory_girl in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

I normally use this step to set up records with factory_girl:

```
Given /^the following (.+) records?:$/ do |factory, table|
  table.hashes.each do |hash|
    Factory(factory, hash)
  end
end
```

And here's my work-around when setting up associations:

```
Given the following group record:
  | id | name |
  | 1  | foo  |
And the following item records:
  | name | group_id |
  | bar  | 1        |
  | baz  | 1        |
  # ...
```

I know this is bad. Using ids makes the whole thing brittle and cryptic from the vantage of the domain person.

So, my question is -- what would be the best practice to set up an association with factory_girl and a table argument like the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my own question: [Pickle](http://github.com/ianwhite/pickle)

Answer (score 3):

You can define multiple associations in a factory.
Like the following :

```
Factory.define :item do |item|
    item.name          "item_name"
end

Factory.define :group do |group|
    group.name          "group_name"
    group.items         { |items| [ items.association(:item), items.association(:item) ] }
end
```

Doing a `Factory(:group)` will create your group uplet with two items in it.

Comment: The trick here is that group.items should return an array.  It took me a while to work that out.

Comment: Yeah that's not easy to understand (but seeing how it works, it's logical)

Comment: Got you. But is there a way to wrap a cucumber step with a table parameter (like the one in my post) around such a factory?

Perhaps, I should just take a pragmatic approach and be verbose and specific in the step ("Given I have two items, foo and bar, that belong to a group called foo") instead of fussing with tables, but that sounds somewhat like an anti-pattern to me?

Comment: No it's not possible to wrap a cucumber step inside a factory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the defined FactoryGirl Cucumber steps:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/lib/factory_girl/step_definitions.rb

You can setup your items and your group(s) in just one Cucumber step:

```
Given the following items exists:
  | Name     | Group        |
  | Foo      | Name: Bar    |
  | Foam     | Name: Bar    |
  | Food     | Name: Bar    |
```

When doing it like this, the creation of group 'Bar' is using 'find_or_create_by' functionality, so the first call creates the group, the next 2 calls finds the already created group.

In this way all 3 items will have same group 'Bar', and you can create as many grouped items as you need.

Comment: The FactoryGirl Cucumber steps are being deprecated by ThoughtBot in favor of writing better scenarios.  See their blog post: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/25650434584/writing-better-cucumber-scenarios-or-why-were